# what does /** mean in c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I was trying to add a block comment in c++, but I made a type-o and wrote `/**` instead of `/*`. I noticed that the comment inside got in bold. Does anyone know what it means?

Comment: It means "comment followed by asterisk" in C++, but it might mean something else in your particular editor/IDE, unfortunately you neglected to mention what that is.

Comment: It means that your editor likes to draw comments starting with "/**" in bold.

Comment: Everything between `/*` and `*/` is a comment as far as the compiler is concerned. Maybe your particular code editor has an extra feature to bold the text when additional `*` characters are used. The compiler doesn't care about that.

Comment: It doesn't **mean** anything in a C++ context; but your editor believes you are writing a [literate program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming).

Comment: It could be that your editor was already trying to emphasise the comment block you are ending with `*/` as you type the `*` using bold.

Comment: Im using the CodeBlocks IDE. I tired to compile but it send an error saying no paramaters in line 5. That line is in the middle of my bold 'comment'

Comment: I think many places have standardized `*` as bold marker and `__` as underline marker. (notably email readers) Code Blocks just makes some pretty print but it has nothing to do with C++, the grammar parses `/*` and wait for the next `*/` ignoring everything in the middle.

Comment: @JoseAngelCazares Please don't leave important information relevant to your question in comments only. Edit your question to make it clearer. Also, if you get an error message when compiling, please provide the ***exact error message***. Vague error messages are usually uninformative. As for your problem, others have indicated that a documentation tool may be integrated into your IDE. It is also possible that the tool is integrated into your build process; and the error you're seeing is actually a documentation error.

Comment: Finally... if you're getting a compile error: ***Show the code!***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This form of comment is used by [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) - This software enables one to generate documentation for the source code. Please see the web site.

I guess your IDE understands this.

Answer (score 2):

In Java this comment style `/**` indicates that the comment is a [javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc), maybe your editor is trying to make a similar distinction. I know that at least the Eclipse IDE will exhibit this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nlmanual/docblocks.html) and [JavaDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) answers.
These are the special comment blocks, that your editor may be able to detect.

```
/**
 * ... Javadoc comment ...
 */
```

---

```
/*!
 * ... Qt style comment ...
 */
```

*intermediary starts are optional

---

```
///
/// ... Doxygen supported ...
///
```

---

```
//!
//! ... Doxygen supported ...
//!
```

Keep in mind, from the C++ language standard, these are all just regular comments.